# Customer receiving "Recoverable Error: Object of Class" message on checkout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, shipping, error-message

A customer has reported that they are receiving an error when they try to check out in our Magento 2.3.2 site. The message is as follows:

> Recoverable Error: Object of Class Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region
>   could not be converted to string in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
>   on line 3101

And there is also a message in shipping which states

> Sorry, no quotes are available for the order at this time

This is happening intermittently for a few customers and I would like to know what is causing it and, if possible, how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Apparently this is a bug which occurs when the region field is empty.

Found a workaround on Github here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7387#issuecomment-263586330

In

> vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

Search for the line in the error (in this case 3101) the text there should be as below

```
        case 'varchar':
        case 'mediumtext':
        case 'text':
        case 'longtext':
            $value  = (string)$value;
            if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
                $value = null;
            }
            break;
```

Replace this with:

```
        case 'varchar':
        case 'mediumtext':
        case 'text':
        case 'longtext':
            if ($column['COLUMN_NAME'] == 'region' AND !is_string($value)) {
                $value = '';
            }
            $value  = (string)$value;
            if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
                $value = null;
            }
            break;
```

Obviously I'm not happy with replacing info in the core files but until a better solution presents itself this will have to do.